# Noise suppression circuits for a 120VAC motor

Tags: ac, tvs, snubber, transient-suppression, varistor

I am building a circuit for a relay that controls power to a 1000 watt pump motor. I want to do what I can to reduce noise and failure of the circuits from transients etc.

Here is my schematic:

[image]

I have decided to also use thermally protected MOVs rated at about 275V. I also decided to use a BZW50-180B TVS diode to help smoothen out transients as they are faster than MOVs from what I understand. All of that and the addition of 2 RC snubbers.

[BZW50-180B datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00000695-1795739.pdf)

[TMOV datasheet](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=e3b6da0b-f146-4399-be72-6e5d81659866&filename=littelfuse-varistor-tmov25s-datasheet)

[F862 datasheet](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_F3092_F862_X2_310.pdf)

Focusing on the AC side of the schematic:

- Will my snubbing circuits work?
- Did I pick an okay value for R4 and R5?
- How many watts should R4 and R5 be?

Comment: Just a MOV alone should be more than adequate. MOVs have significant capacitance that go some  way to snub the transient. For the snubber resistors a 1W or greater metal oxide. You can purchase 100nF/100R snubber combinations. Its a bit hard to follow your schematic - use a relay symbol rather than a box. You could eliminate the opto as the relay gives you galvanic isolation.

Comment: The relays is controlled by an PCF8574 IO Expander. The PCF8574 can only source/sink about 25mA. That relay coil is about 200mA. Are you saying i can get a capacitor with a built in resistor?

Comment: You still would need Q1 to drive the relay. Yes, you can get specific snubbers comprised of a capacitor and resistor from the likes of Kemet and others. You could put the snubber across the relay contacts and the MOV across the load.

Comment: I'm looking at a kemet 43II3250(1)01(2)(3). It claims to have 0.25uF capacitance. How is this going to compare to 0.1uF. They didn't have any 180/188VAC versions.

Comment: [Quencharc](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=quencharc&t=opera&ia=web) are purpose-made for applications like this.